# Windows new install, old user directory super slow

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I added a new physical disc with a fresh install of Windows 10. The old disc is now as let's say drive E:

When I use the file explorer to access the old Users directory, it takes ages to access. There are not that many personal files inside, because I usually save files on a third drive.

I am assuming it is making or updating some kind of database of the files inside.

How can I speed up this process? I am planning to move the important files still remaining there to a new directory.

Comment: "I am assuming it is making or updating some kind of database of the files inside." - Have you taken ownership of this folder? Windows does not use a "database" to handle permissions.

Comment: Not permissions, but things like thumbnails? Indexing for search-related stuff? That is the point I do not know why it takes so long.

Comment: A User profile directory is owned and only accessible by that User (or a system administrator on that system), a system administrator from another system, would have to be added to the ACL.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of the NTFS permissions. The NTFS file system stores permissions for each file and directory.

When you access the old user folder for the first time Windows will ask you if you really want to access it. Then it will add your user to the permission list. This is very slow but normally only for the first time.

What I do when transferring files from an old installation is to copy them to a FAT32 drive and all permissions will be gone.

Comment: I will consider the option to use a fat32 USB, for now, patience is the safest option.